# jQuery close button isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function getdata(id){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "mapa_llamadas.php",
           data: { 'id' : id }, 
           success: function(data) {

                var resultado = $.parseJSON(data);
                var html = '';
                var contador = 0;
                for (var columna in resultado){
                    contador++;
                    if(contador == 12){
                        contador = 1;
                    }

                    var num_parcela = resultado[columna]['num_parcela']; 
                    var finca_registral = resultado[columna]['finca_registral'];
                    var ref_catastral = resultado[columna]['ref_catastral'];
                    var uso_1 = resultado[columna]['uso_1']; 
                    var uso_2 = resultado[columna]['uso_2'];
                    var sup_m2_parcela = resultado[columna]['sup_m2_parcela'];
                    var edif = resultado[columna]['edif'];
                    var aprov_neto_m2 = resultado[columna]['aprov_neto_m2'];
                    var situacion = resultado[columna]['situacion']; 
                    var adjudicatario = resultado[columna]['adjudicatario']; 
                    var coord = resultado[columna]['coord'];

                    html += '<ul><li><strong>Número de parcela:</strong> '+num_parcela+'</li><li><strong>Finca registral:</strong> '+finca_registral+'</li><li><strong>Referencia catastral:</strong> '+ref_catastral+'</li><li><strong>Uso 1:</strong> '+uso_1+'</li><li><strong>Uso 2:</strong> '+uso_2+'</li><li><strong>Superficie:</strong> '+sup_m2_parcela+' m<sup>2</sup></li><li><strong>Edificio:</strong> '+edif+'</li><li><strong>Aprovechamiento neto:</strong> '+aprov_neto_m2+' m<sup>2</sup></li><li><strong>Situación:</strong> '+situacion+'</li><li><strong>Adjudicatario:</strong> '+adjudicatario+'</li></ul>';

                    ///alert(contador + "index:" + columna + "\n value" + resultado[columna]['num_parcela']);
                }
                $('#mostrarparcela').html('<button title="Cerrar ventana" class="mfp-close"><i class="mfp-close-icn">&times;</i></button>'+html);
            } 
        }); 
}
```

This exact line isnt working (it should close the window that appears):

```
$('#mostrarparcela').html('<button title="Cerrar ventana" class="mfp-close"><i class="mfp-close-icn">&times;</i></button>'+html);
```

`#mostrarparcela` are a number of `<area></area>` tags in my html file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the close functionality? Like show this button.mfp-close get associated with a click handler?

Comment: @stakolee I dont have a close functionality, I guess thats my issue xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was missing, this is what I needed to add to make the close button functionality work:

```
$('#mostrarparcela').html('<button id="close" title="Cerrar ventana" class="mfp-close"><i  class="mfp-close-icn">&times;</i></button>'+html);

$( "#close" ).click(function() {
    var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance; 
    magnificPopup.close(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add close function to button.
Try with

```
<button title="Cerrar ventana" class="mfp-close" onclick="javascript:window.close();"><i class="mfp-close"><i class="mfp-close-icn">&times;</i></button>
```

Comment: Please don't use `javascript:` inside an inline event handler.

Comment: it's onclick="window.close();" enough?

Comment: Yes. If you want to learn more about event handling, I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.